# Run a JS function when HTML is rendered after page load and all AJAX requests have been made

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I bumped into a problem the other days and I tried a few solutions that proved not to be as good.

The problem:

1. On my page I have HTML generated from the CMS, and a few AJAX requests that interact with the HTML (adding more content in some areas of the page).
2. This page is long so when I am on other page and click to a link on this page it needs to go down to a certain area on the page; it will scroll me on page load, but after the scroll, some HTML still renders because of AJAX requests.
3. The scrolling is made with spliting the URL and get the ID written in URL. Then scroll to that ID on page.
4. I tried:

   - $(window).load(function() {});
   - $(document).ajaxStop(function() {});
     and still not working ...
5. So what I am trying to do is to wait until:

   - all AJAX requests are done and also;
   - the HTML generated to be loaded/rendered on page 
     and after that to do the scroll to that area on the page.

Thank you in advance for your responses!

Comment: Check for async: false for ajax requests

Comment: @user3263194 that is terrible advice. `async: false` should **never** be used, it blocks other scripts

Comment: Is your code in control of the ajax loads (or are they 3rd party plugins)? P.S. *Never use `async: false`*. That creates far more problems than working *with* the way browser aysc processes work.

Comment: Yes, I'm in control of the AJAX requests. I'm just using the CMS API to provide some better functionality that the default functionality.